# How to perform Cntrl + A functionality using Selenium with the code written in C#

Tags: c#, selenium

This is the code I am using:

```
Actions act =new Actions(driver);
act.SendKeys(Keys.Control);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use actions, sendkeys supports this:

element.SendKeys(Keys.Control + "A")